# Applications of Extrema

Tags: calculus

A company wishes to manufacture a box with a volume of 16 cubic feet that is open on top and is twice as long as it is wide. Find the width of the box that can be produced using the minimum amount of material.

A) 2.9 ft

B) 2.2 ft

C) 5.8 ft

D) 4.4 ft

Can someone walk me through how to do this one? I have several word problems like this and I am unsure of where to start with it. I know that I am probably going to need to use a formula for the volume of the box but other than that I am pretty lost.

Comment: Don't really get why this is being down voted I just want to know how to do it

Comment: First you need to come up with a function $f(\text{width})=\text{amount of material}$

Comment: More concretely: can you see how to use the area and volume of a box for this problem?

Comment: can you attempt to explain it I previously attempted it but I do not believe I did it correctly as I did not get any of the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only material required for the box is for the base and for four sides. Denote its width by $w$, its length by $l$, and its height by $h$, and you immediately have:

$l = 2w$ (it is twice as long as it is wide)

$w \times l \times h = 2w^2h = 16$ (given volume of the box)

Then you work out the surface area of the box. That's equal to the area of the base ($w \times l$) plus the area of the four sides (two of which are area $w \times h$ and the other two of area $l \times h$), so in total:

$SA(w, h, l) = wl + 2h(w + l)$

We know that $l = 2w$, and $h = 8 / w^2$ from the first two equations, so we can write the surface area solely as a function of width (which is important because the question asks for you to find the width for a particular surface area):

$SA(w) = 2w^2 + \frac{16}{w^2} (2w + w) = 2w^2 + \frac{48}{w}$

Finding the width that minimises the surface area (i.e. the amount of material used) should then be straightforward.

Comment: so from there do I just plug in my answer choices and see which gives me the smallest answer or what? Because if i solve for w I am left with 1

Comment: Actually I just did it is the answer 2.2ft?

Comment: I have no idea how you're left with 1. You find the value of w that minimises SA(w) by differentiating and solving, and for that I get that $w=\sqrt[3]{12}$ which is about 2.3 ft.